# Animation ramps up seed and slows down

Tags: animation

I have an animation that slowly increases its speed and slowly stops. How do I stop it from doing this? I have set it to linear extrapolation but it still does the same thing.

Comment: Not extrapolation, but **interpolation**. Meaning: the kind of transition between two keyframes. Set the interpolation to Linear.

Comment: @susu Thank you so much. Everyone was telling me it was extrapolation.

Answer (score 2):

Not extrapolation, but interpolation. Meaning: the kind of transition between two keyframes. Set the interpolation to Linear. @susu